# Single word for 'I think it is right but not exactly sure about it'

Tags: word-choice

Could somebody suggest a single word for 'I think it is right but not exactly sure about it'.

I can say 'I am almost sure' but wondering if a word exists with same meaning.

Comment: A _single_ word? How about ***probably***? Single words don't often carry quite so much information in them.

Comment: **prabably** is half by half chance, isn't it? Here want to say "I am almost sure" (like 80-90% sure about that!)

Comment: Not half/half, no. More like 70/30, if I were to put a number to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confident

implies a high degree of sureness, but not quite certainty.

Answer (score 0):

> [I believe ...](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Believe?s=t)
>
> [I assume ...](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Assume?s=t)

"Assume" shows the speaker takes it for granted.

Answer (score 0):

dubiety: [1. A feeling of doubt that often results in wavering. See Synonyms at uncertainty.
2. A matter of doubt.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dubiety)

In your example, the person is dubitative

Incertitude:

[1. Uncertainty.
2. Absence of confidence; doubt.
3. Insecurity or instability.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incertitude)

Peradventure
.
[1.chance, doubt, or uncertainty.
2.
surmise.
adverb
3.
Archaic. it may be; maybe; possibly; perhaps.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peradventure)

Scepsis:

[1 philosophic doubt.](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/282390/scepsis)